# Powershell - Opening Excel Docs

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that converts an Excel file into a CSV. However, before I can even get started with this, I'm running into an unexpected error - see code below.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
```

This gives the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Not sure why but it doesn't recognise the Workbooks.Open method. Any help much appreciated!

Cheers,
Nick

UPDATE:

Guessing this has something to do with my firm's IT infrastructure - I can list the object properties, just not call the above described methods.

Comment: Is Excel installed?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes Excel is installed. Strange as most of the scripts online seem to suggest this code should work...

Comment: The error message would imply that either `$Excel` or `$Excel.Workbooks` is `$null`, if the first one is null then check the GAL to see if Excel is registered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an out of the box solution but I use this for years and it works fine for me beside some specific tuning I had to make.

https://gist.github.com/adgedenkers/34345b773376a508fa65a207ba47695e

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately this also doesn't work for me. Getting an error when trying to add the Workbook as it uses similar methods as tried above